# Predis sub/pub on multiple channels with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis, predis

**Hi every one **,

I'm using predis with laravel in microservice architecture, and I have the following scenario :

**App 1 :**

- in a controller I published an event in the 'timeslot' channel.

```
Redis::connection('timeslot')->publish('timeslot/updateStatus', json_encode([
    'timeslot' => $this->timeSlot,
    'customer' => $this->file->customer_id
]));
```

**App2:**

- I subscribed to this channel 'timeslot' and I have a process that makes a modification in a model (that works).
- I have a listener in this model when updating I launch another redis event to app 1 in other channel (event)

```
static::updated(function (TimeSlot $model) {
if($model->isDirty('state') && $model->state->value === 'booked'){
      $result = json_encode(array_merge($model->toArray(), $model->agency->toArray()));
           Redis::connection('event')->publish('timeslot/booked', $result);
      }
});
```

when executing this part I would have the following error:

```
fclose(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource

at vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php:247
    243▕      */
    244▕     public function disconnect()
    245▕     {
    246▕         if ($this->isConnected()) {
  ➜ 247▕             fclose($this->getResource());
    248▕             parent::disconnect();
    249▕         }
    250▕     }
    251▕
```

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfYAy.png)
Any help please.
Thank you

I tried to do it on same channel but also i got an error

Comment: Hi! Do you get this error during running tests? Predis has an issue, maybe it is related to your case: https://github.com/predis/predis/pull/34

Comment: @llia Yatsenko it's not during the tests it's in the normal execution of the application